# Gradient of an absolute value function in n dimensions?

Tags: vector-analysis

Problem: For x ∈ $\mathbb{R}^n$, calculate ∇$\ \frac{(1)}{abs(x)}$

I tried to take the gradient of both the negative and positive versions, but I just don't know how to do it in n dimensions.

Here is the original problem: [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R759Z.png)

Edited for clarity

Comment: Hi. Welcome to MSE. I don't fully understand your notation. Perhaps you mean $\nabla |x|$? Further, by "absolute value" (of a multidimensional variable) you mean its Euclidean norm?
Further, why do you say "infinite dimensions"? If we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have multiple (but finite!) dimensions, right? Please clarify.

Comment: Why are you talking about infinite dimension? Your vector $x$ is in a finite-dimensional space.

Comment: The 'infinite dimensions' part of this question does not make sense. Otherwise, just compute the partials of $x \mapsto {1 \over \sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots x_n^2}}$.